# How to add faces to underside of a model

Tags: faces, 3d-printing

[image: Bottom_Row_Verts]

Hi. Attached is an image of just the bottom verts of a model that I have. I have hidden the top section so it can easily be seen.
I plan to print the model, so this is the open underside face, I need to create faces on this underside to effectively close the model, would anyone know an easy way of doing this?

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks.Richard.

Comment: Does selecting the vertices, then pressing F to make a face work?

Comment: If you're going to print it the geometry will be triangulated which might not work as expected if filling an Ngon with F. You could try to convert this shape into a curve with Alt+C, then set the curve type to 2D and set Fill type to something other than None. I don't think there are any other easy ways.

Comment: Have you tried creating a circle, and then using mesh addons to bridge between all of the vertecies of the model and the circle, then just F with the circle created to make a face? If that works, let me know

Comment: Thank all. I managed to sort and print the model with copying the top part of the model, extruding then scaling global Z to scale 0. Much appreciate everyones comments. Thanks! again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I managed to sort and print the model with copying the top part of the model, extruding then scaling global Z to scale 0. Much appreciate everyones comments. Thanks again.

Comment: Please expand this. An image or two showing how you did this. Explaining how to access the extrusion and scaling. Things like that. It will improve the usefulness of this answer to other people with similar problems.